# How to replace a section of an audio file using sox (retaining all metadata)

Tags: sox

I want to replace a section of audio1.aif with the contents of audio2.aif. The original file, audio1.aif, has metadata that I want to keep intact so I'd rather replace the section of the original file than create a new file.

I can't find a 'replace' or similar command for sox.

Example:

```
audio1.aif = 5 seconds 0--1--2--3--4--5
                             ^^^^^^^
audio2.aif = 2 seconds       0--1--2
```

Replace seconds 2-4 of audio1.aif with the contents of audio2.aif.